# jQuery on('resize') not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some jQuery to dynamically position an element. While it works on load, it doesn't work when the window is resized.

The code I have:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var offset = $("#kDropdown").offset();
      //$(".hidden-dropdown").css('position', 'absolute')
      //$(".hidden-dropdown").css('left', offset.left);
      $(document).on('resize', function () {
        $(".hidden-dropdown").css('position', 'absolute')
        $(".hidden-dropdown").css('left', offset.left);
      }).trigger('resize');
    });


      <div class="hidden-dropdown hide">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
          <hr />
          <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
          <hr />
          <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Attach the event to the window instead of document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the one resized is the `window`, hence:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    console.log("yay");
});
```

You can attach it with the `resize` method directly:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log("direct yay");
});
```

They are both the same.

Comment: For whatever reason, the element I'm trying to move doesn't with this but the event is being triggered.

Comment: Then There's more background here. Check that the event is being called by adding a `console.log` inside. Also check that there's actually an offset by adding a `console.log` of the offset. And last, be sure that the `.hidden-dropdown` exists. Also, you can access the DOM (F12) and check that the `.hidden-dropdown` element has the new styles applied. If you right click the element, you can inspect it and that will open the DOM directly to that element.

Comment: The styles are not being applied but the event handler is working. Can I even dynamically rerender styles? I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: Yeah, the `$(".hidden-dropdown").css('position', 'absolute')` lines are fine. You can add CSS dynamically, don't worry. If the callback is fired then the `css(..)` codes are ran. The only reason I can find is that jQuery don't find the elements (check that the `$(".hidden-dropdown")` selector is actually selecting elements). If it don't find elements is that they do not exists in the same frame (check for typos and such). Also maybe the problem is that other part of the code in the page is removing the styles.